# Why does Stripe's handleCardPayment not run in my Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, stripe-payments

I am trying to use Stripes handleCardPayment to process a charge following a payment intent. I can't get the handleCardPayment function to run inside another Javascript function.

I have tried to debug my code step by step. The Javascript function runs and will print out an alert to the window.

The Javascript variables I set at the top of the function also get set.

The handleCardPayment() function however does not seem to run?

I have attempted a try/catch to see if I can catch the error coming from the request but nothing is logged.

I am a little stumped as to where the issue is with this? although I suspect it might be something basic that I am missing on calling the stripe function correctly.

```
function completePayment() {

 // Assign client secret from PHP session variable

 var clientSecret = "<?php echo $_SESSION['c_secret'] ?>";

 try {

  stripe.handleCardPayment(
   clientSecret, cardElement, {
    source_data: {
      owner: {email: "<?php echo $_SESSION['m_usr_email'] ?>"}
    }
   }
  ).then(function(result) {
     if (result.error) {
        alert("Error in payment");
      } else {
        alert("Success in payment");
      }
    }); 
  }
  catch(error) {
   console.log(error.message);
  } 
}
```

My payment intent is created on a separate PHP page. This works correctly and a payment intent is created in stripe with an associated client secret.

How the app currently functions:

- User presses 'Subscribe' button.
- Ajax request runs and POSTS to a separate PHP file
- PHP file creates the payment intent and saves the client secret in a PHP SESSION variable
- Ajax 'Complete function()' then calls 'completePayment();'
- Javascript function 'completePayment();' is located just before the closing  tag at the bottom of the page.
- Debugging 'completePayment()' shows that the function does execute following the Ajax 'Complete function()' call.
- stripe.HandleCardPayment fails to do anything.
- cardElement is a global Javascript variable set when the card element is created (this is created on initial page load).
- I have debugged both PHP SESSION variables and confirm that they have both been set with the correct information prior to using them in the handleCardPayment function.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Hmmm, so no errors in the browser console? Since you're using PHP to populate the client secret and email: when you `view source` on your page, you can confirm these two fields are populated by an email and client secret? PHP should populate them from the SESSION vars at the time of page load, if you're doing the AJAX request after PHP renders the page they could still be empty.

Comment: Hi duck, I echo out the session variables and they are definitely populated correctly prior to running the handlecardpayment. I have testing running this part from a separate function call on a test button, after creating the payment intent and it does run so I will close this question as now I have to implement my error handling code to try and find out what the errors are in payment processing! For some reason the function does not run from the Ajax complete function but I can alter my code to do the payment intent before pressing the subscribe button so should be workable.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. It looks like the function it does not execute becouse the console logs does not appear but  after searching I saw that I missing $intent->client_secret, before that, the js console not show me anything and I had to call only the function stripe.handleCardPayment without any code extra  then the cosole show me $intent->client_secret It was undefined.

I don't speak english very well I hope that It will serve somebody